# How import key to AWS Lambda from AWS KMS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to figure something out.. how should I get a key from AWS KMS inside Python code running on AWS Lambda. I have keys for remote server FTP/SFTP inside AWS KMS, and now my AWS Lambda function has to mirror files from remote server to S3 bucket, but some servers are using ssh-key to authorization. The question is how can I import the key (decrypt it, save in plaintext- so I have to decrypt it inside python code with boto3 in every run of function?) in python code?

Regards,
Null007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AWS KMS in AWS lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620182/how-to-use-aws-kms-in-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [answers to this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620182/how-to-use-aws-kms-in-aws-lambda), you would just need to attach a role with KMS key retrieval permissions to your Lambda function.

After that, you should be able to access the KMS keys using the boto3 client:

```
with open('encrypted_pem.txt', 'r') as encrypted_pem:
    pem_file = encrypted_pem.read()

kms = boto3.client('kms', region_name=REGION)
return kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(pem_file))['Plaintext']
```

[code also courtesy the answers to the linked StackOverflow question]